# How to clear textboxes besides using JS

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am building an app using MVC, and this question pertains to the `Create` page and action.

Lets say my model has 2 decimal properties along with other properties but aren't necessary for this example:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public decimal DecimalProperty { get; set; }
    public decimal SecondDecimalProperty { get; set; }
    // more properties below this, but deemed unnecessary for this question
}
```

Obviously these properties are non-nullable, so in my `Create` View they appear as so on page load (**ignore the 2nd textbox**):

[image]

Now my goal is to clear those textboxes out, so they are just blank.. so I used JS to achieve that by doing:

```
$(".clear-textbox").val("");
```

I put a class called `clear-textbox` on those input fields.. works perfectly.. but now in my `HttpPost Create Action` I have conditional statements checking to see if other fields are valid, and if not return the object.. like so:

```
if (object.property== 0)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("property", "This field is required!");
    return View(object);
}
```

This results in the `Create` view to be redisplayed with the values that the user has already entered, along with an error message below the one property that needs to be changed.. and this is where the problem lies.  Once the `Create` view is reloaded.. then so are the scripts for `clear-textbox`, resulting in `DecimalProperty` and `SecondDecimalProperty` to be empty text-boxes.. instead of keeping what the user originally entered for them.

So my question, is there another way to clear out textboxes for decimal properties other than using javascript?

Any help is appreciated.

---

### **UPDATE**

Here is the cshtml.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DecimalProperty, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DecimalProperty, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control clear-textbox" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DecimalProperty, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mind putting some of your view code in this post? If you pass in a value and use an Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DecimalProperty), it should show the value that was passed into the view.

Comment: @JesseMoreland I think we are on different pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you have to do it via Javascript on load like following

```
$(".clear-textbox").each(function(){
    if($(this).val() <= 0 ) 
        $(this).val("");
});
```

OR

You can create your own **MVC Html Helper** which will do things as you need for your special needs. Let me know if you want code for that...

[You can also refer this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/720515/Custom-HTML-Helper-for-MVC-Application)

Comment: ahh omg why didn't I think to compare to 0.0... thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default value as a `data-` attribute of the textbox and clear it only if they match. Like:

```
$(".clear-textbox").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if( $this.val() == $this.data().defaultvalue ) $this.val('');
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to work. If I leave a required field blank.. my controller will see that and return the object as is (leaving the values that the user entered in the corresponding textboxes), except for the decimal properties because of `clear-textbox`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to come up with an answer without knowing how the text boxes are being rendered. However, I'm assuming you are using something like

```
@Html.TextBoxFor
```

or

```
@Html.EditorFor
```

There are two ways to do this.

#### 1. Add a DisplayFormat attribute to the model fields and use EditorFor:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:#.#}")]
    public decimal DecimalProperty { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:#.#}")]  
    public decimal SecondDecimalProperty { get; set; }
}


@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DecimalProperty)
```

#### 2. Use the inline format attribute:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DecimalProperty, "{0:#.#}")
```

Comment: updated the question.. also what you posted will not help with the the clearing out of the textbox when returning the object.. I need the textbox to ignore the `clear-textbox` class when returning an error to the user